# Running into errors trying to filter Pandas DF to show only dates over a week

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date

I have created this df by reading in three files.

```
        SUBREF   SAMPNUM  ... WORKTABLELOGDATE EXPORTED
30     C468633  10552705  ...       2020-06-09      NaN
44     C649747  20380271  ...       2020-06-16      NaN
112    P026530  50482919  ...       2020-04-29      NaN
113    P026530  50482920  ...       2020-04-29      NaN
140    C055419  50485482  ...       2020-05-12      NaN
...        ...       ...  ...              ...      ...
15308  C725492  99036976  ...       2020-04-27      NaN
15318  S714508  99037098  ...       2020-06-18      NaN
15319  S714508  99037098  ...       2020-06-18      NaN
15320  S714508  99037100  ...       2020-06-18      NaN
15321  S714508  99037100  ...       2020-06-18      NaN
```

Using this code

```
WORKTABLE = pd.read_excel('C:/WORKTABLE.XLS', usecols =['SUBREF','SAMPNUM','DET','LOGDATE','SUITE', 'SECTION'], converters= {'LOGDATE': pd.to_datetime})
SAMPLESTABLE = pd.read_excel('C:/SAMPLESTABLE.XLS', usecols = ['SUBREF','SAMPNUM', 'LOCATION','LOGDATE','COMPDATE','REPDATE'], converters = {'EXPORTED': pd.to_datetime})
CBSEXTERNAL = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/CBSEXTNL.XLS', usecols = ['SUBREF','EXPORTED'])
DF3 = pd.merge(left = SAMPLESTABLE, right = WORKTABLE, how='outer', on=['SAMPNUM','SUBREF'])
DF3.rename(columns={'LOGDATE_x':'SAMPLETABLELOGDATE','LOGDATE_y':'WORKTABLELOGDATE'}, inplace=True)
DF3 = DF3[['SUBREF','SAMPNUM','LOCATION','SECTION','DET','SUITE','SAMPLETABLELOGDATE','WORKTABLELOGDATE','COMPDATE','REPDATE','WORKTABLELOGDATE']]
DF4 = pd.merge (left = DF3, right = CBSEXTERNAL, how='outer', on=['SUBREF'])
```

What I want to do is filter the col WORKTABLELOGDATE to show anything over 7 days old. I've tried various methods but I always end up with the errors

```
FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'.  Currently, the
'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future pandas will
not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised. To retain the current
behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with
'pd.Timestamp'.
```

and

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

What I tried is variants of

```
DF7SEROLOGY = DF7SEROLOGY[DF7SEROLOGY['WORKTABLELOGDATE'] < weekago]
```

I've tied re-indexing DF3 and DF4 using

```
DF4.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but that didn't help any.

What am I doing wrong?

Expected Output as requested using the today as 23/06/20

```
        SUBREF   SAMPNUM  ... WORKTABLELOGDATE EXPORTED
30     C468633  10552705  ...       2020-06-09      NaN
140    C055419  50485482  ...       2020-05-12      NaN
```

Comment: *What I want to do is filter the col WORKTABLELOGDATE to show anything over 7 days old*,  could you show a example of your expected output?

Comment: No problem. I put it in the question at the bottom.